# Why cannot build ServiceProvider when using Scrutor and registering an open generic type as implemented interface

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, scrutor

Please help me to understand why the following code works and why do I get System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot instantiate implementation type 'Concrete1[TOther]' for service type 'IInterface1[System.String]'.' if I uncomment the only commented line.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Extensions;
using Scrutor;

public interface IInterface { }

public interface IInterface<T> where T : class { }

public abstract class AbstractClass<T> : IInterface<T>, IInterface where T : class { }

public class Concrete<TOther> : AbstractClass<string> { }

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        services.Scan(x =>
        {
            x.FromApplicationDependencies(a => true)
                .AddClasses(t => t.AssignableTo(typeof(IInterface<>)))
                .UsingRegistrationStrategy(RegistrationStrategy.Replace())
                //.As(type => type.GetInterfaces().Where(v => v.IsGenericType && v.GetGenericArguments().Length == 1).ToArray())
                .AsSelf()
                .WithLifetime(ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
        });

        var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
}
```

Comment: The generic argument `TOther` can't be mapped to the interface. Ask yourself, if you request an`IInterface<string>` from the DI Container, which closed version of `Concrete<TOther>` should it return? What should it fill in for `TOther`? I have no clue and neither does the DI Container. Please describe what behavior you want to have, and we'll try to find a solution for this.

Comment: @Steven before building `ServiceProvider` I want to register all closed versions of `Concrete<TOher>` so that in runtime I could get services like `Concrete<string>`, `Concrete<int>`, etc. I understand how to do that.  I just did not understand why the commented line if uncommented broke the program. I guess I got it, thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

`Concrete<TOther>` is a generic type which can't be constructed without passing generic type parameter, i.e. something like `Concrete<string>` which can't be done by the DI. Basically your registration will be analogous to:

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IInterface<string>), typeof(Concrete<>));
```

So when user will resolve `IInterface<string>` (`sp.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetService<IInterface<string>>()`) the provider should be able to do something like `new Concrete<>` which obviously is not possible.

Build-in DI container allows registering open generic services with open generic implementations, something like:

```cs
services.AddScoped(typeof(Concrete<>));
services.AddScoped(typeof(IInterface<>), typeof(Concrete<>));
```

But this requires concrete to be declared as:

```
public class Concrete<TOther> : AbstractClass<TOther> where TOther : class { }
```

If it suits your needs then you can mimic that with Scrutor next way:

```cs
services.Scan(x =>
{
    x.FromApplicationDependencies(a => true)
        .AddClasses(t => t.AssignableTo(typeof(IInterface<>)))
        .UsingRegistrationStrategy(RegistrationStrategy.Replace())
        .As(type => type.GetInterfaces()
            .Where(v => v.IsGenericType && v.GetGenericArguments().Length == 1)
            .Select(t => t.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
            .ToArray()) // or just .As(typeof(IInterface<>))
        .AsSelf()
        .WithLifetime(ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
});
```

> I just did not understand why the commented line if uncommented broke the program. I guess I got it, thank you for clarification.

It breaks the program because it tries to register closed generic service `IInterface<string>` as open generic type which is impossible.

Comment: This does not exactly what I need although is a good trick. My `Concrete<TOther>` knows how to close the abstract class. But its consumers should know how to close the concrete class itself

Comment: @Alexander there is no way to provide the `TOther` when resolving `IInterface<string>`, i.e. `sp.GetService<IInterface<string>>()` should return some closed generic type (because you can't construct an open one), but you registration says to create an open generic i.e. `Concrete<>`.

Comment: I understand that. But I am going to only resolve `Concrete<>` types, so this should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Alexander yes, this will, though you should understand that unless you are resolving collection of `IInterface<string>` only last one will be returned.

Comment: Last one what ?

Comment: @Alexander so for example you will register `AddScoped<IInterface<string>, Concrete<int>>(); AddScoped<IInterface<string>, Concrete<string>>();`, then when resolving `IInterface<string>` you will get `Concrete<string>`, not `Concrete<int>`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253354/discussion-between-alexander-and-guru-stron).